# Origin and development of the tradition that Torah scrolls are exact to the letter from Moses

Tags: provenance, sefer-torah, mesorah-tradition

The claim that our Torah scrolls are copied exactly to the letter from Sinai or "for thousands of years" is very common and is used frequently by Rabbis and Kiruv organizations to prove Torah's holiness and inerrancy. For example, [Aish.com site](https://www.aish.co.il/h/sh/to/48863557.html):

> **איך אנחנו יודעים שהתורה המצויה ברשותנו כיום, מכילה את אותו טקסט שניתן בהר סיני?**
> במקורה, הוכתבה התורה למשה, אות אחר אות. המדרש מספר, שמשה כתב שלושה עשר ספרי תורה לפני פטירתו. שנים עשר מהם חולקו בין 12 השבטים והספר השלושה עשר הונח למשמרת בתוך ארון הברית (יחד עם הלוחות). אם יקום מישהו וינסה לשנות את התורה, יבוא הלוח שבארון ויעיד נגדו (ובאותה מידה, אילו תהיה לאותו אדם גישה אל ארון הברית והוא ינסה לשנות את הספר המקורי, יבואו שנים עשר הספרים האחרים ויעידו נגדו).
> מאז נכתבו ספרי תורה רבים. כיצד היו בודקים את דיוקם? ספר תורה מקורי נשמר תמיד במקדש שבירושלים וכל שאר ספרי התורה נבדקו בהשוואה אליו. לאחר חורבן בית המקדש השני, בשנת 70 לספירה הנוצרית, נהגו חכמי ישראל לערוך בדיקות מחזוריות נרחבות, על מנת לשרש כל טעות סופרים.

Another renowned Israeli Rabbi - [Eliezer Melamed](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/1661):

> אחד הפלאים שבתולדות ישראל הוא המסורת המדויקת של ספר התורה, שלמרות כל השינויים במנהגים ובאורחות החיים בין כל קהילות ישראל, ספרדים, אשכנזים ותימנים, מסורת כתיבת ספר התורה נשארה אחידה. זאת למרות שספרי התורה הועתקו במשך אלפי שנים, ספר מספר, במקומות שונים בעולם תוך כדי נדודים מגלות לגלות, ואע"פ כן כל הספרים שווים בסדר המילים והאותיות, ואף במסורת הטעמים והנקודות לא נפלו שינויים.

---

It is clear that the obligation of exact copying of the Torah scroll is absent from the Torah and scriptures. Similarly, Mishnah does not mention this rule (and pretty much ignores the subject of writing Kosher scrolls in general IMHO)

Many Talmudic sources openly suggest that the tradition/Halachah was not observed by [all] Talmudic sages (see Kiddushin 29-30, [Soferim.6.4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Soferim.6.4?vhe=Talmud_Bavli,_Vilna_1883_ed.&lang=he), [Tifeeret Israel 67](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/tifeeret/67-2.htm) and more) or at least they used scrolls that were never exact to the letter also some Talmudic evidence of scribal rigor exist (see [Menachot.29b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Menachot.29b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Who originated the tradition that Torah scrolls were passed unchanged to the letter from Moses?

Comment: I’m not aware that such a tradition exists

Comment: See the very first line of Gemara, with Rashi’s commentary.

Comment: Can you provide a single source that mentions this tradition?

Comment: I can name several that attest to the opposite, including bavli, yerushalmi, sifre, and every rishon that I am aware of that addresses it, as well as manuscript history. I'm not the downvoter, but what makes you think such a tradition exists? The halacha is that when copying a torah, we are careful not to change a letter. But that does not mean to say historically such an error never happened.

Comment: Probably a misunderstanding of the Rambam's basic of faith of Torah min Hashamayim. Classes I've heard on this subject usually either open up with this basic of faith or discuss it somewhere in-between.

Answer (score 1):

The source in Soferim you cited says there were three scrolls with only one word different in each. That means the rest was the same.

And you can't just say "Many sources say" and then provide no sources to back up that claim.

Comment: This is not an answer. To comment please use the comment section.